# Computing the determinant and trace of a $10 \times 10$ matrix with a particular block form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let A be a $ 5 \times 5 $ skew-symmetric matrix with entries  in $ \mathbb{R} $  and B be the $ 5 \times 5 $ symmetric  matrix whose  $ (i.j )^{th} $ entry is the binomial coefficient $ \begin{pmatrix} i \\ j \end{pmatrix} $ for $ 1 \leq i,j \leq 5 $.
>   Consider the $ 10 \times 10$ matrix , given in the block form by $$ C =\begin{pmatrix} A & A+B \\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix} .$$
>   Then,
>
> (a)  $\det C=1$ or $-1$,
>
> (b) $\det C=0$,
>
> (c) trace of $C$ is $0$,
>
> (d) trace of $C$ is $5$.

Since $A$ is skew-symmetric, we have $\det A=0$. Hence $\det C=\det(A) \det(B)=0$. **But how to find the trace of $C$ ?**  **I need help**

Comment: Skew symmetric matrices do not have to have $det = 0$.

Comment: @Paul The precise result is that skew symmetric $n \times n$ matrices with $n$ odd have det=0. We are here in this case.

Comment: It will be $ 1\leq i\leq j\leq 5 $  ,instead of $ 1\leq i ,j\leq 5 $  , otherwise  the matrix  $B $ wouldn't be symmetric. and hence $ B $ is the $ 5\times 5 $ identity matrix.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I have to give an answer. Unless I am mistaken, the trace of $C$ is simply $Tr(C) = Tr(A) + Tr(B)$. Since $A$ is skew-symmetric, we have $A=-A^T$ and from this can deduce that $Tr(A)=0$ (can you figure this out?)

In his comment, Paul says that the determinant of a skew-symmetric is not necessarily $0$. But, if I am not mistaken, for matrices of odd dimension it is necessarily true.

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: No,  the trace is given  $ \ 5 $

Comment: @mabmath Sure. The trace of $C$ is $5$, but the trace of $A$ is zero, since $Tr(A) = Tr(-A^T)$ or $Tr(A) = - Tr(A)$ and finally $Tr(A) = 0$. In fact, one can prove the stronger claim that the diagonal of $A$ is zero, since $A=-A^T$ implies $a_{ii} = - a_{ii}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

1. The eigenvalues of a real skew-symmetric matrix are imaginary, and so its nonzero eigenvalues come in pairs.
2. By skew-symmetry, the diagonal entries of any skew-symmetric matrix are all zero.
3. Since ${i \choose j} = 0$ for $j > i$, the matrix $B$ is lower triangular. (in fact, by definition this matrix is essentially the first five rows of Pascal's Triangle, padded with zeros).

Comment: One could show that skew-symmetric matrices are singular (for odd sizes) and of trace zero without using or knowing about eigenvalues.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That's a good point, and this is easy: All one needs to know is the definition of skew-symmetric, that $\det A = \det (A^{\top})$, and that $\det(\lambda A) = \lambda^n \det A$, where $A$ has size $n \times n$.